# how to create a caller graph in sphinx for python?

Tags: python, graphviz, python-sphinx

Is it possible to create a caller graph (a graph which funcion calls the function xy) in sphinx ?
i know this feature from doxygen (for java) and really liked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx has the capability to incorporate graphviz diagrams with the [sphinx.ext.graphviz](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/graphviz.html) module.

If you're looking to generate call graphs, you can run [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/en/master/) from sphinx and embed the images.

Comment: looks like `pycallgraph` has not been updated since 2013. Was hoping to find a way to do this for an entire module with submodules, and have them display on Read the Docs

Comment: pyan3 seems a more up-to-date option for generating the dot file - see https://github.com/davidfraser/pyan

Comment: @andrew-walker Sphinx must have changed their link since your post (10 years ago!) so I just fixed it.